# Adicionar um Document a uma Array no MongoDB

Tags: java, array, mongodb, document-db

Essa semana, comecei a mexer com MongoDB (nunca tive muito contato com nenhum DB antes) e acabou de surgir uma dúvida que não estou conseguindo resolver(pesquisei, acredite).

Vamos ao seguinte contexto:

```
    @Listener(targets = ExceptionUncaughtEvent.class)
private static void onException(ExceptionUncaughtEvent e){
    MongoCollection<Document> col = DogoBot.db.getCollection("BOT");

    if(!col.find(new Document().append("ID", "STATISTICS")).first().containsKey("EXCEPTIONS")){
        col.findOneAndUpdate(new Document().append("ID", "STATISTICS"), new Document().append("$set", new Document("EXCEPTIONS", new ArrayList<Document>())));
    }
    Document doc = new Document()
            .append("CLASS", e.getClass().getName())
            .append("DATE", Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
            .append("WARN_LEVEL", e.getWarnLevel().toString());
    col.updateOne(
            new Document().append("ID", "STATISTICS"),
            new Document().append("$push", new Document().append("EXCEPTIONS", doc)));
    e.getReporter().report();
}
```

E no Database, tenho:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a18b83a252ee4305cc83880"), "ID" : "STATISTICS", "EXCEPTIONS" : [ ] }
```

Meu objetivo aqui é primeiramente checar se existe uma array chamada "EXCEPTIONS", caso não exista, crie uma. (Não sei se esse passo é necessário, se não for me avisem por favor).

Seguindo disso, criar um Document com todas as informações da Exception que ocorreu, e adicioná-lo a array EXCEPTIONS no Database.

Porém, isso não acontece (em vez disso, na collection, cria-se vários Documents *"{"EXCEPTIONS":[]}"* ).

Alguém sabe o motivo? Pode me explicar por que isso não funciona? Obrigado pessoas